# Drupal Commerce : Shopping Cart Checkout for Orders

Tags: 7, commerce

What I'd like to do is have an order page where the user see's a list of all products.

They'll then fill out the quantities they want and click on 'checkout'  .

So it'd look like how the Cart looks once you've added products

[image]

Has anyone done this or anything similar.   I'm currently looking at using Drupal commerce on Drupal 7.

Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial thought is for you to check out the commerce_add_to_cart_extras module.  Granted, it's still in its dev version, but you can create a view with products, specify quantity, and bulk-ly add to cart.

To go straight to checkout, you may need to add a little redirect in the submit handler for that button.